# How to invoke Kotlin object method using reflection in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection

I want to invoke setApiHelper method in the below code using java reflection. How can I do so?

```
object PlayerUtils {
    private var apiHelper: String? = null
    fun setApiHelper(apiHelper: String) {
        this.apiHelper = apiHelper
        println(apiHelper)
    }

    fun getApiHelper(): String? {
        return this.apiHelper
    }
}
```

**My Implementation**

```
private static void testingPlayerUtils() {
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName("reflection.PlayerUtils");
            cls.newInstance();
            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("setApiHelper");
            method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), "TESTING");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this gives an error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class TestingReflection2 can not access a member of class reflection.PlayerUtils with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at TestingReflection2.testingPlayerUtils(TestingReflection2.java:20)
    at TestingReflection2.main(TestingReflection2.java:14)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you want to access `object` declared in Kotlin using Java code, you can do like below code snippet:

```
PlayerUtils.INSTANCE.setApiHelper("");
//or
PlayerUtils.INSTANCE.getApiHelper();
```

Now that being said, in order to access methods of `PlayerUtils` in Java using reflection, you'll need to access it's static member called `INSTANCE` first.

And you can do that by using `Field` from `Class` declaration, something like below:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("reflection.PlayerUtils");
Object instance = cls.getField("INSTANCE");
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("setApiHelper");
method.invoke(instance, "TESTING");
```

Refer [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html) for detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set accessible true for the method as below -

```
 Class<?> cls = Class.forName("reflection.PlayerUtils");
 cls.newInstance();
 Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("setApiHelper");
 method.setAccessible(true);
 method.invoke(cls.newInstance(), "TESTING");
```